# Primary/Foreign keys in Easy Table in Azure App Service Mobile Apps

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

I am following this [article](http://www.kashyapas.com/2015/12/26/setting-up-easy-tables-in-azure-app-service-mobile-apps/) to create tables in Azure Mobile service as Easy tables in portal without using any Code or SQL server management studio.

But I don't find any option there to set the primary key or foreign key for a column.

Please suggest me some ways of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About Primary Key azure will create a Primary key automatically for you.

If you need a foreign key you should just connect to the SQL Azure that it creates for you and modify the tables in side the SQL Azure using TSQL.

In general if your DB structure is too complicated with a lot of relationships you should think of coding your own service as these easy tables as their name suggest are for "Easy" stuff to give you a boost start...

Comment: Agreed - Easy Tables are meant to be easy to get started.  They quickly break down when you deal with relationships, indexing and so on.  If you need anything other than a basic table, don't use Easy Tables - code your own ASP.NET or Node.js site.